# Can I fix VMware Fusion to correctly map the tilde / back tick on a British keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, internationalization, vmware

I'm stuck with an odd keyboard layout in [Fusion Player v 12.0.1](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Fusion/12.1.0/rn/VMware-Fusion-1210-Release-Notes.html) on macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina) and cannot seem to find a way around it.

The keyboard physically is a bluetooth Apple keyboard UK layout with tilde/back tick between he left shift and Z keys. This is set to 'British' in the system preferences and works fine (i.e. I can type `~§± and the correct symbols show in applications.

I'm running a new VM with Debian 10 in it but cannot find a way to get these keys to map correctly despite working in copy from Mac / paste to VM fine.

Is there a solution to the crossed over keys?

Comment: Since you said latest version I’ve linked to that. Please edit this if I guessed the wrong version of latest for your macOS and if you are using fusion pro instead of fusion player.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install VM Tools from the Fusion Menu (ignore notice about using open-vm-tools)
2. Select keyboard & mouse from the VM settings
3. Highlight `Profile - default` on the list of profiles
4. From tools (cog below list of profiles) - select duplicate and name 'Debian Profile'
5. From tools - set profile as default
6. Double click profile and select Keyboard and Mouse
7. Make sure Enable Key Mappings is **checked*
8. Make sure Language Specific Key Mappings is **not checked**
9. Use the '+' to add a new mapping of **From:** § **To:** `
10. Use the '+' key to add a new mapping of **From:** ` **To:** §

e.g. for the first mapping:

[image]

That should then take effect once you have a session running.

On the Debian side, you may have to configure the keyboard from the command line if you have not set it up / not running multiple languages.

First check if `cat /etc/default/keyboard` gives you:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="apple"
XKBLAYOUT="gb"
XKBVARIANT="mac"
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

If so, ignore the rest and pat yourself on the back / get a cuppa :-)

If not install the command line configurator:

```
sudo apt install keyboard-configuration
```

Then execute it:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

Select:

- Keyboard Model: **Apple**
- Keyboard Layout: **English (UK) : English (UK, Macintosh)**
- AltGr: **Right Alt (AltGr)**
- Compose Key: **????** - I do not use one - select as needed
- Control+Alt+Backspace to terminate: **????** - your choice

Then **REBOOT**

The other way is to add the Keyboard Layout Handler into a panel BUT this sticks a big blob of text on your menu bar!  If you are happy with this (or are switching languages) then the UK keyboard can be set as:

[image]

Note the checkboxes for **do not reset options** and **keep system layouts** are clear.

Comment: Superbly well done explanation of a tricky sequence of steps

Comment: Thank you kindly; I've been messing around with kinto and other solutions to get this working and finally found your writeup.